# Get complete url in HttpRequestProcessor

Tags: pipelines, urls

I want to get the complete URL in `HttpRequestProcessor` pipeline.
When I hit https://www.abc.com/#section-1, currently `args.RequestUrl` is not returning the section path. How to get complete URL with section after #.

Comment: See this - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2440/httpcontext-current-request-url-doesnt-return-language-code
Try this - HttpContext.Current.Request.Url

Comment: no this is not working . its giving url before #.

Comment: Why do you want to process the anchor link (`#section-1`) on the server side? Kindly update your question with more information.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to retrieve the #anchor from the server side in ASP.NET because the browser won't send these anchor fragments to the server. This is a client-side flag to tell the browser to move to a specific place within the page. You can use some JavaScript code in the body onLoad event to check for an anchor and send it back to the server using Ajax.

```
var anchorValue;
var url = document.location;
var strippedUrl = url.toString().split("#");//or use window.location.hash
if(strippedUrl.Length > 1)
    anchorvalue = strippedUrl[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Anchor tags (ex: `#my-anchor`) aren't considered part of a URL and are not sent to servers. You can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067491/is-the-anchor-part-of-a-url-being-sent-to-a-web-server

For example, see this page: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html

Click around on the table contents links. Notice that additional requests are not made to the server. They are meant to be used as `"jump links".

If you want to expose the anchor to the server, consider serializing it as a query string: `?my-anchor=anchor-name`. From there it's business as usual on the server side: `args.RequestUrl.PathAndQuery`.