# Get Url with section value in HttpRequestProcessor

Tags: sitecore-api, pipelines, redirect

I am building redirect module where i need to get the request url from browser with section value.
Example : https://www.site1.com/news#category1.

I am not able to get #category1 in code using args.requesturl.

How to achieve this.

Comment: Check this - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/34357/get-complete-url-in-httprequestprocessor

Comment: no I see they mentioned its not possible on server side and asking to use some javascript and send to server. I am looking for way handle via pipeline code.